# Need helping adding ACF User link to code using ACF User field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How do I get the users link here as well. I am using the ACF user field as an Array.

```
<?php
$user = get_field("medically_reviewed_by");
if( $user ): ?>
    <h3>Medically Reviewed By: <?php echo $user['display_name']; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you

I am not sure what exactly I need to add. I tried the other version of doing as an object with:

```
<?php
$users = get_field("medically_reviewed_by");
if( $users ): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_attr($user->user_url); ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But this doesn't get the link either just leaves the href blank.

Here is the custom code in the functions.php file for the new user role:

/* Create Medical Reviewer User Role */

```
add_role(
    'medical_reviewer', //  System name of the role.
    __( 'Medical Reviewer'  ), // Display name of the role.
    array(
        'read'  => true,
        'delete_posts'  => true,
        'delete_published_posts' => true,
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'publish_posts' => true,
        'edit_published_posts'   => true,
        'upload_files'  => true,
        'moderate_comments'=> true, // This user will be able to moderate the comments.
    )
);
```

Comment: You can inspect the variable by doing `var_dump($user);`

Comment: I got ["user_url"]=> string(0) ""

Comment: What is the ACF field type in the backend. Is it a [Link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/link/)? You can also run `var_dump(get_fields())` to see everything associated with the current post which is sometimes helpful. Are you in the main WordPress loop, or outside, such as in the header or footer?

Comment: The ACF field type is the User. Do I need to create a separate link ACF field to pull the users link also? I thought that the User field could pull all associated data within the user?

I am within the main Wordpress Loop also.

Comment: To be very clear, the "Field Type" is set to "User" which is under the "Relationship" category? What is the "Return Format" set to?

Comment: Yes the "Field Type" is set to User and "Return Format" is currently set to Object. So I am using the "Object" version above. I have been trying both formats.

Comment: Unfortunately you've got me stumped. Is it possible that that user is deactivated or something? Can you try setting a different user?

Comment: This is a custom User Role that I created for this specifically that has been added to blog posts. Could it be I didn't add the correct user data? I will add that above to main thread of the code in the functions.

Comment: I also created a brand new user and set it to the new user role "Medical Reviewer" and the name shows up but the URL doesn't still and leaves the href with nothing.

Comment: Is it possible that you have Yoast installed have the Author Archives disabled?

Comment: Just checked and they are enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stumped at this point. (Personally, we never associate content with Users on the sites that we build. It is totally valid and not wrong to do that, but we've found over time that users can churn, and that some content needs to be "owned" by users that never log in, and both result in a bunch of dead accounts that are security issues. Instead we always make dedicated CPTs to back our users, and we sometimes associated that 1:1 with users for convenience. This doesn't really help you, but I just wanted to throw that out there.)

Comment: We do have the authors assigned to the posts. This is an additional Role that a medical expert has looked over the content and is signing off on it. Just a pain that I have the code that works to link to the authors profile, but can't get it to work for this other users profile. I have also reached out to ACF to see maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @ChrisHaas so I figured it out. The way that code is, it’s calling the website field. (I’m stupid and should have tried that), but I would prefer it to be automated and go to the /author/name url without having to enter it in the user website field.